# What are some present day examples of mathematics that needs to be made rigorous?

Tags: soft-question

Hundreds of years ago, calculus, while still very useful, lacked rigor. It was later made rigorous and put on a sound basis by Dedekind and others. Another example is intuitive set theory, which was made rigorous by Zermelo. Are there any present day examples of mathematics that lacks a solid foundation, but which could possibly be made rigorous in the future?

Comment: Physics gives examples. I think there are calculations in quantum field theory that provide a lot of insight into the physics but haven't yet been elevated to the status of theorems.

Comment: I'm not sure this counts, but you might be interested in [this article on issues in symplectic geometry](https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-fight-to-fix-symplectic-geometry-20170209/).

Comment: There's no agreed upon definition of [weak n-category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_n-category), but there's a lot of theory about how they "should" behave.